# Proving that two matrices commute

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> If $A$ and $B$ are matrices in $M_n(\mathbb C)$ such that there exists $\lambda$ in $\mathbb C$ such that $\lambda AB + A + B = 0$, then prove that $A$ and $B$ commute.

I do not know how to approach this problem.

Comment: Could you please provide some more context? Where did you encounter this problem? What have you tried so far? Have you tried considering a particular case (e.g. $n=2$)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** For the case that $\lambda \neq 0$,
$$
\lambda AB + A + B = 0 \implies (\lambda A + I)(\lambda B + I) = I.
$$

Comment: After rewriting $A=-(\lambda B+I_n)^{-1}B$ how do you conclude ? Is it true that $(\lambda B+I_n)^{-1}$ is still an (infinite) polynomial of $B$ even if $\left\lvert\lambda\right\rvert\left\lVert B\right\rVert\geqslant 1$ ?
In that case, we get $AB=BA$ easily, but I do not know if this is correct.

Comment: @Flewer Yes, it is true that $B$ is an analytic function of $B$, and you could indeed use this to get $AB = BA$.

Comment: Alternatively, proceed directly:
$$
B(\lambda B + I_n)^{-1} = ([B + \lambda I_n] - \lambda I_n)(\lambda B + I_n)^{-1} = I_n - \lambda (\lambda B + I_n)^{-1},
$$
and similarly $(\lambda B + I_n)^{-1} B = I_n - \lambda (\lambda B + I_n)^{-1}$. Use this to conclude that $AB = BA$.

Comment: You mean 
$$B(\lambda B+I_n)^{-1}=([B+\frac{1}{\lambda}I_n]-\frac{1}{\lambda}I_n)(\lambda B+I_n)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\lambda}I_n-\frac{1}{\lambda}(\lambda B+I_n)^{-1}$$
?

Comment: @Flewer47 Whoops, that was a silly mistake. In any case, yes, that's what I had in mind